# How do I properly declare a global variable in a header file?

Tags: objective-c, global-variables, extern

I was testing some code where I declare a global variable in a header file, but I'm getting a linker error: "duplicate symbol"

header file:

```
//
//  GlobalVaraibleClass.h
//  GlobalVar
//


#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int gGlobalVar = 0;
@interface GlobalVaraibleClass : NSObject

@end
```

class file:

```
//
//  GlobalVaraibleClass.m
//  GlobalVar
//

#import "GlobalVaraibleClass.h"

@implementation GlobalVaraibleClass

@end
```

main:

```
//
//  main.m
//  GlobalVar
//

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "GlobalVaraibleClass.h"
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    @autoreleasepool {

        extern int gGlobalVar;

        NSLog(@"Hello, World! %i", gGlobalVar);

    }
    return 0;
}
```

where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is backwards, the extern goes in the header, the declaration setting the value goes in the implementation file.

The `extern` specifies that the variable will be declared somewhere else. If the declaration is in the header every time the header is included there will be another declaration and at link time there will be multiple definitions which will not link.

Example:

```
//  GlobalVaraibleClass.h
        extern int gGlobalVar;

//  GlobalVaraible.m
#import "GlobalVaraibleClass.h"
int gGlobalVar = 3;

//  main.m
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "GlobalVaraibleClass.h"
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {

        NSLog(@"Hello, World! %i", gGlobalVar);

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I see. How come it allows you to declare it in your main file outside the function using "int gGlobalVar = 0" and getting the reference to it in a function in the implementation file using "extern int gGlobalVar"? Which way would be better practice?

Comment: To be a global it must be defined outside of any function.